# Can I speed up the dialogue text?

Tags: ios, phoenix-wright-ace-attorney

Phoenix Wright on iOS seems to show the text slowly one character at a time. Is there a way for the text to show up without the lag?

If not, is there a version where you can play without lag?

Answer (score 1):

You can press and hold on the "Next Message" button to fast forward text. The [American app store description](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ace-attorney-phoenix-wright/id365681816?mt=8) also confirms this.

Comment: That just makes it so that the text is barely shown not shown quickly